# What is the az cli equivalent of Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

The Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan works fine in PowerShell. I am trying to achieve the same using `az cli` but am unable to find an equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks there is no built-in command in azure cli, the workaround is to use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) to call the REST API directly.

**Sample**:

1.Start a compliance scan at resource group scope - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy-insights/policystates/triggerresourcegroupevaluation

```
az rest --method POST --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/triggerEvaluation?api-version=2019-10-01
```

2.Start a compliance scan at subscription scope - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy-insights/policystates/triggersubscriptionevaluation

```
az rest --method POST --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/triggerEvaluation?api-version=2019-10-01
```

After running the command, you could check the result in the `Activity log` in the resource group/subscription, it works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is currently possible using:

```
az policy state trigger-scan
```

More in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/state?view=azure-cli-latest#az-policy-state-trigger-scan